# center justify ul inside column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know lot of questions has already been asked about centering an `<ul>` element inside a Bootstrap column but what I would like is to center the `<ul>`but not centering the text (I want every `<li>` to be vertically align).

Here's my code:

```
<div class="content-menu">
  <h1 class="content-header">Information</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ul class="content-menu-menu">
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/info.png">Information</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/dollar.png">Pricing</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/more.png">Supplements</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/placeholder.png">Map</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my css:

```
.content-menu-menu {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
}

.content-menu-menu > li {
  color:white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.content-menu-menu > li > a > img {
  width: 32px;
  height:32px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

But here's what I got:
[image]

What I would like is that the list is on the center of the screen but every items are left aligned.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: in `.content-menu-menu` set `text-align: justify` in `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">` you can add `text-center` class

Comment: This doesn't work :/ It align every items verticaly but align them on the left, not on the center of the column

Comment: you need to set the size of div to perfect align

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  You say `center`, you say `left`, but you then say `vertically aligned`.   BE SPECIFIC: What do you want for left / right alignment? And what do you want for top / bottom alignment?

Comment: See answer, this is how I wanted them. I don't know how to tell this kind of stuff, it's horizontally center but items are horizontally align.. Well this has been resolved so it's ok..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below. content-menu (center) and content-menu-menu > li (left) adjusted.

```css
.content-menu {
text-align: center;
}

.content-menu-menu {
  float: none;
  padding:0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-menu-menu > li {
  color:white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content-menu-menu > li > a > img {
  width: 32px;
  height:32px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="content-menu">
  <h1 class="content-header">Information</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ul class="content-menu-menu">
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/info.png">Information</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/dollar.png">Pricing</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/more.png">Supplements</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="link"><img src="images/placeholder.png">Map</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```